# CENTOS Vs Windows 2008 R2

Tags: centos, mysql, tomcat, java

We have an application running on Windows Server 2008 R2 with Apache WAMP, Tomcat, Mysql, PHP and java SE for last 4 years. Its a Web based ERP application.

I would like to know if it makes sense to migrate this application to CENTOS ( or any other linux variant) and what will be the tradeoff or benefits and if we will encounter any technical issues?

Comment: You can move to CENTOS if you do not have any php or other module dependencies which is only restricted to Windows. I have earlier moved few servers from Windows to Linux RHEL and CENTOS and faced few issue like font and some css issue which are very common. But if you are aware of those things then move it confidently. There will b few issues but that can be resolved until it is completely related to windows only.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know if it makes sense to migrate this application to Linux

It makes perfect sense.
Apache, MySQL and PHP are "more" native to Linux than they are to Windows, so they may perform better.

> What will be the tradeoff or benefits and if we will encounter any technical issues?

Always assume that you'll encounter technical issues.

My advice for you there is, do some research up front to make sure that you have your logging set up correctly, because when the time comes, it will be your only source of information to help you troubleshoot your issues.

Most of the time if you Google what you see in your error logs, there will be somebody online who has dealt with it previously.

You should also do some research into securing your Apache installation, and possibly set up a very basic configuration of SELinux, which will greatly increase your server security.

Comment: We have had some chinese hackers earlier entering our server. We did a Microsoft Basic security audit and did some strengthening of our securirty. Can I take it that security environment on linux will be better than windows ?

Comment: What kind of hack it was ?Did they get in to your server using admin pass or via application vulnerability. If it was application vulnerability then moving to Linux also will not help much. Fix the application bug and then think of changing the application server OS.

Comment: SELinux can, in some cases, protect against attacks in ways that regular security like firewalls and user authentication cannot. I suggest looking into the basics of SELinux, because it adds an extra layer that can stop attackers who happen to exploit your server application.

Answer (score 0):

What is your goal with this migration? It's usually not a good idea to migrate something to another platform just for the sake of it. You'll need convincing reasons why the new platform will be better than the old one.

Also consider the following:

- What platform you are more familiar with: If you know your current platform and have little experience with Linux, it will be a tough ride and it's very easy to do many things wrong or suboptimal and thus eliminate the perceived advantages of the new platform. This is double-true for security-related issues - Linux is not magically more secure than Windows.
- What is the rest of the environment running? This is somewhat related to the platform experience you have, but also to the management of the systems - it's always easier to manage less platforms.
- Are the problems you have and that makes you consider the switch inherent to the platform or your specific environment? If it is the latter, switching will not help. Again, that is also true for security issues.